# Selenium wont Regonize XPath that shows on devtools

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

[image]

[image]

I am trying to validate that the comment I posted on my profile shows up on my wall and profile feeds. The comment always gets posted; however, selenium cannot recopgnize the posted comment. The xpaths show in devtools but I get the following error in selenium:

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of proxy element.

Here is the locator in homeLocators:

```
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH ,using="(/html/body/main/div/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[last()-1])/div[2]/div[2]‹")                      
public WebElement firstPostLastComment;
```

Here is the locator in profileLocators:

```
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH ,using="(/html/body/main/div/section/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div)[last()-1]/div[2]/div[2]")
public WebElement firstPostLastComment;
```

Here are the functions in my actions file:

```
public void postCommentProfile() {
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");
    String random = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String randomShortened = random.substring(random.length() - 10);
    commentProfile = randomShortened;
    profileLocators.firstPostCommentInput.clear();
    profileLocators.firstPostCommentInput.sendKeys(randomShortened);
    profileLocators.firstPostCommentInput.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}

public void newCommentShowsOnWallAndProfile() throws InterruptedException {
    navLocators.navProfile.click();
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");
      new WebDriverWait(SeleniumDriver.getDriver(), 60)
      .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(profileLocators.firstPostLastComment));
    boolean flag = true;
    String expectedText = commentProfile;
    System.out.println("this is expected text in newCommentShows" + expectedText);
    String profileActualText = profileLocators.firstPostLastComment.getText();
    System.out.println("this is profile actual text in newCommentShows" + profileActualText);
     if(!profileActualText.equals(expectedText)) {
          flag = false;
          System.out.println("flag false fired");
      }
    
    navLocators.navHome.click();
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");
      new WebDriverWait(SeleniumDriver.getDriver(), 60)
      .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(homeLocators.firstPostLastComment));
    String wallActualText = homeLocators.firstPostLastComment.getText();
    System.out.println("this is wall actual text in newCommentShows" + wallActualText);
    if(!wallActualText.equals(expectedText)) {
          flag = false;
      }
    Assert.assertTrue(flag);
}
```

I get the following error if I take out the waits:

Org.openqq.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression.

Here is the link to the app
https://spbk.herokuapp.com/#/login

Comment: So which exception is raised `TimeoutException` or `InvalidSelectorException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably come up with a better xpath, although the suggesting to search by text will likely be more robust if you can do it.

To do so, if your test generates the random string first then calls

```
@Test public void should_post_comment()
{
  String randomCommentText = generateRandomComment();
  postCommentProfile(randomCommentText);
  newCommentShowsOnWallAndProfile(randomCommentText);
}

public String generateRandomComment()
{
  String random = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  String randomShortened = random.substring(random.length() - 10);
  return randomShortened;
}

public void postCommentProfile(String randomShortened) {
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");
    profileLocators.firstPostCommentInput.clear();
    profileLocators.firstPostCommentInput.sendKeys(randomShortened);
    profileLocators.firstPostCommentInput.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
```

But if you really can't get the text or change the test steps so that you have the text, you can still get an element with an explicit locator.  Given the example app listed above, to get the most recent comment (last) on the most recent post (top) I'd use an XPATH like this:

```
//div[@class='body-content-col'][1]//div[@class='post-comment-article group'][last()]
```

This will give you something like this:

```
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH ,using="(//div[@class='body-content-col'][1]//div[@class='post-comment-article group'][last()]")                      
public WebElement firstPostLastComment;
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this XPATH section //div[@class='body-content-col'][1] says "give me the first div with class "body-content-col" -- in other words, each post. The [1] is the first index.

Comment: The second part of the XPATH //div[@class='post-comment-article group'][last()] says "give me the last element that is a div with class post-comment-article"

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use relative xpath instead of absolute ones. Here's how you can do it:

Assume your comment is:

> "My Test Comment"

You can locate in following manner:

```
browser.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='My Test Comment']"));
```

This is just a sample. You can look for better XPath locators.

Comment: The comments are randomly generated strings. That won't do.

Comment: @AlecLivinghouse , so put your *randomly generated string* into variable. What's the problem?

Comment: @JaSON in the function newCommentShowsOnWallAndProfile, I am trying to verify that the comment actually shows up where it's supposed to. Right now, the xpath to select the comment after it has been posted is not working. Therefore, I cannot verify it.

Comment: @AlecLivinghouse - as i suggested you would need to use relative path. Now what I had shown is just an example, it need not be that way exactly. In order for you to ensure that the comment does shows up in your desired section on the page I would suggest that you add some prefix element where the comment is suppose to show up. If you can post full DOM section of the desired section containing this comment element we will be better able to assist you